# File exist in assets but is throwing an FileNotFoundException

Tags: assets, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to access photos saved in the assets folder, my code doen't work all the times.

i have 16 sub-folders in assets with photos in **png** format each have between **30kb ~ 60kb**

Each folder have between 100 and 400 photos

Full size of assets folder is 113mb.

My code **stoped working when i added more photos to the assets**

```
 public Bitmap getImg(String ID, String pic){
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        //Exemple: II/1.png 
        istr =  getAssets().open(ID + "/" + pic +".png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
}
```

When i run this code i get a FileNotFoundException, but the file existis (i am awere that file names are case sensitive, extension is in lowercase and pic names are numbers).

I think this is something to do with the file size, because i compressed all photos in one of the subfolders and it started to work again, but on the other folders (that have alot more photos) don't, even after compressing i keep getting a FileNotFoundException.

is there a better way to store or access the photos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue by changing the format from PNG to JPG